# Why is my phone not loading a table in libgdx?

Tags: android, libgdx

For some reason, my android phone will not load a table even though I have it being drawn. It shows up on the desktop version, but not on the android version. You can see my adding it in the render() method in the if statement. It loads perfectly on my desktop. This is only showing the code I used for the table. The desktop version and phone version has the same camera size. Everything else appears on my phone except for this table.

```
  public class game implements Screen {


    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        tManager.update(delta);

        backBatch.begin();
        splash.draw(backBatch);
        backBatch.end();

        stage.act(delta);
        stage.draw();

        world.step(TIMESTEP, VITERATIONS, PITERATIONS);

        table2 = new Table(skin);
        table2.setBounds(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

        int numContacts = world.getContactCount();
        if (numContacts > 0) {
                table2.add(heading3).spaceBottom(35).row();
                table2.add(replayButton).spaceBottom(15).row();
                table2.add(menuButton);
                movement.x = -sSpeed;
                movement.y = 10;
                movement.rotate(720);
                stage.addActor(table2);
                Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
        }

        debugRenderer.render(world, camera.combined);
    }

    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        camera.viewportWidth = 450;
        camera.viewportHeight = 250;
        camera.update();
        stage.setViewport(450, 250, true);
        stage.getCamera().translate(-stage.getGutterWidth(), -stage.getGutterHeight(), 0);
        if (table != null){
            table.setSize(450, 250);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void show() 
    {
        stage = new Stage();

        world = new World(new Vector2(0, 0), true);
        debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();

        camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

        //replay button
        replayButton = new TextButton("REPLAY", skin);
        replayButton.addListener(new ClickListener() {
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y)
            {
                ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new game());
            }
        });
        replayButton.pad(15);

        //main menu button
        menuButton = new TextButton("MAIN MENU", skin);
        menuButton.addListener(new ClickListener() {
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y)
            {
                ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new MainMenu());
            }
        });
        menuButton.pad(10);

        //game over
        heading3 = new Label("game over", skin);
        heading3.setFontScale(2);
    }

        private void createCollisionListener() {

            //collisions in world
            world.setContactListener(new ContactListener() {

                public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
                }

                public void endContact(Contact contact) {
                }

                public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold oldManifold) {
                }

                public void postSolve(Contact contact, ContactImpulse impulse) {
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: Please provide only those code where you are getting error and which is important.

Comment: Is the desktop window size the same as your Android device's screen size?